# Mipmapping in Python?

Tags: python, qt, numpy

I am looking to build a mipmapping program using QtCreator and Python. So far, my application looks like this:

[image: Design]

Where you can upload an image to the program, and it will show you the original image in the left label box. When you press create mipmap, it is supposed to show you the mipmap in the right label box.

When you upload a photo, it looks like so: 
[image: Program]

The next part is where I am stuck. Is there a mipmapping algorithm to use in Python? I saw this [question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14549696/mipmap-of-image-in-numpy) that is a little bit helpful, but I can't install numpy because it doesn't recognize my Python 3.4, although it is installed.

So Here is what I do have so far:

```
from __future__ import division
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtOpenGL
from PyQt4.QtGui import * #Used to import QPixmap. DO NOT REMOVE.
from PyQt4.QtCore import * #Used to import Qt.KeepAspectRation. DO NOT REMOVE.
import sys, os
import mmCreator



class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, mmCreator.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyApp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.btnSelect.clicked.connect(self.select_image)
        self.btnConvert.clicked.connect(self.mipmap)
        #self.btnDownload.clicked.connect(self.download)


    def select_image(self):
        self.origImage.clear()
        image = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                                              "Select Image",
                                              "",
                                              "Image File (*.jpg *.png *.gif)")
        pixmap = QPixmap(image)
        scaledPixmap = pixmap.scaled(self.origImage.size(), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        self.origImage.setPixmap(scaledPixmap)
        self.origImage.show()


    #def mipmap():
```

So, is there another way to create mipmaps aside from numpy that I can implement in my program?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [QPixmap.scaled](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qpixmap.html#scaled-2) to create a half width or height image.

```
# Create pixmap from source file
pixmap = QPixmap('/path/to/file')

# Create scaled versions of source file.
mipmaps = []
mipmaps.append(pixmap.scaledToWidth(pixmap.width() / 2))
mipmaps.append(pixmap.scaledToWidth(pixmap.width() / 4))

# Merge scaled images into a single image
w = sum([m.width() for m in mipmaps])
h = max([m.height() for m in mipmaps])
merged_pixmap = QPixmap(w, h)
painter = QPainter(merged_pixmap)

x = 0
for mipmap in mipmaps:
    painter.drawPixmap(x, 0, mipmap)
    x += mipmap.width()

# Save file.
merged_pixmap.save('/path/to/file.png', 'PNG')
```

Comment: But then what about concatenating the images?

Comment: What are you concatenating?  A mipmap is just a smaller resolution image, right?

Comment: It's a set of smaller resolutions.

Comment: @J-Play I edited the answer.  Can you just create multiple scaled images and save them separately?  Or they have to all be in the same image file.

Comment: I think they have to be the same image file, but I'll keep this code in handy, too.

Comment: I've included a method for merging the images.  Depending on the specific scales of your mipmaps and the dimensions of your image, you may be able to pack the images tighter.

Comment: @J-Play concatenating the images is simply a convention. In Python it would be much more useful to keep the images separate in a tuple or list.

Comment: @Brendan Abel, so it tells me that pixmap doesn't have a scaledTo Width attribute.

Let me edit my question and put up my original code.

Comment: It's there alright. So, I ran `pixmap = QPixmap(image)` like I did in my first function, but then I'm told that my mipmap function takes 0 positional arguments but 2 were given.

Comment: I've figured it out. I think I'm getting the ball rolling here! Thank you for all of your help, @BrendanAbel!!